# How to pass huge list of id (e.g.) to apache spark custom datasource

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using Apache spark 3.0.1. I have implemented custom rest datasource that makes rest api post call to external system. In order to make post call I'm creating dto with list of ids which I'm getting from dataset and passing it via .option("ids", ids). Is there any other way to pass huge list of ids to custom datasource?

```
String ids = "1,2,3";

sparkSession
  .read()
  .format("com.custom.datasource")
  .option("ids", ids)
  .load();
```

Then I'm parsing ids inside my custom datasource and creating dto for post request